# Did the centurion have Saving Faith?

Tags: matthew, jesus, faith

> Matt 8:10 BSB When Jesus heard this, He marveled and said to those
> following Him, “Truly I tell you, I have not found anyone in Israel
> with such great faith.

This Great Faith. Is it Saving Faith?

Comment: Is there non-saving faith?

Comment: Romans 2:6-12 and Acts 10:34-35: “So Peter opened his mouth and said: “Truly I understand that God shows no partiality, but in every nation anyone who fears him and does what is right is acceptable to him.”

Comment: Centurion of Matthew 8 or Cornelius the Gentile of Acts 10?

Answer (score 1):

First things first the centurion in question did not believe that "Jesus was Son of God" instead he believed Jesus could heal his son which is corroborated by this verse

> Matthew 8:13
>
> And Yeshua said to that Centurion, “Go, it will be done for you just as you have believed”, and his boy was healed at that moment.

Second there is no saving by **faith alone**. This is a false teaching which have links to the infamous **Sola Fidae** first suggested by **Martin Luther**. You can't just **"believe Jesus is Son of God"** and expect to go to heaven

**References:**

> James 2:14-17
>
> What good is it my brethren, if a man says, 'I have faith', and he does not have deeds? Can his faith save him? And if a brother or sister is naked and lacking daily food, And any of you will say to them, “Go in peace, be warm, be full”, and he would not give them the bodily necessities, what good is that? **So also faith alone without works is dead.**

> James 2:21-24
>
> Was not our father Abraham justified by works when he offered Isaac his son upon the altar? Do you see that his faith upheld his deeds and by deeds his faith was perfected? And the Scripture was fulfilled which said,”Abraham believed in God, and it was accounted to him for righteousness”, and he was called the friend of God. You see that by works a **man is justified and not from faith alone.**

> James 2:19-20
>
> **You believe that God is One;** you do well; the **demons also believe and tremble.** Are you willing to know, oh feeble man, that faith without works is dead?

> Luke 4:33-34
>
> And there was a man in the synagogue who had the **spirit of a filthy demon** in him and he **cried with a loud voice** And he said, “Let me alone! What business do we have with you, Yeshua Nazarene? Have you come to destroy us? I know you, who **you are, The Holy One of God!**”

> Matthew 7:21-23
>
> It is **not everyone that says to me, 'My Lord, my Lord'**, who enters the Kingdom of Heaven, **but whoever does the will of my Father** who is in Heaven. Many will say to me in that day, 'My Lord, my Lord, have we not prophesied in your name, and in your name have cast out demons, and have done many mighty works in your name?' And then I will confess to them, 'I have never known you, remove yourselves far from me, you workers of evil.'

> Matthew 25:34-39
>
> Then The King will say to those who are at his right, '**Come, blessed ones of my Father, inherit the Kingdom** that was prepared for you from the foundation of the universe.' **For** I was hungry and **you gave me food**, and I was thirsty and **you gave me drink**. I was a stranger and **you took me in**. I was naked and **you clothed me**. I was sick, and **you took care of me**. I was in prison, and **you came to me**.' Then the righteous will say to him, 'Our Lord, When did we see you that you were hungry and we fed you, or that you were thirsty and we gave you drink? And when did we see you, that you were a stranger and we took you in, or that you were naked and we clothed you?' 'And when did we see you sick or in a prison, and we came to you?' And The King answers and says to them, 'Amen, **I say to you, as much as you have done to one of these my little brothers, you have done that to me**.'

> Luke 16:19-31
>
> Parable of the rich man and Lazar
>
> The parable never accuses rich man of not believing in God but his lack of deeds

> Luke 18:18-23 (same as Matthew 19:16-22, Mark 10:17-22)
>
> And one who was a **nobleman asked him** and said to him, “Good teacher, **what shall I do to inherit eternal life?**” 19**Yeshua said to him**, “Why do you call me good? There is no one good except the one God.” 20“**You know the commandments**: 'You shall not murder. You shall not commit adultery. You shall not steal. You shall not testify a false testimony. Honor your father and your mother.' “ **He said to him**, “**I have kept all these things** from my childhood.” But **when Yeshua heard these things, he said** to him, “**You lack one thing: Go sell everything that you have and give to the poor, and you shall have a treasure in Heaven**, and come after me.” But when he heard these things, **it grieved him, for he was very rich**.

> Matthew 5:1-12
>
> For I say to you, that **unless your goodness will exceed** that of the Scribes and the Pharisees, **you will not enter the Kingdom of Heaven**.

> John 5:29
>
> And they shall come out: **those who have done good things, to the resurrection of life**, and those who have done **evil deeds, to** the resurrection of **judgment**.

> 2 Cor 5:10
>
> For we are all going to **stand before the judgment seat** of The Messiah, that **each man will be paid** in his body anything **that was done by him, whether of good or of evil**.

Answer (score 0):

We read in Gal 2:16 -

> know that a man is not justified by works of the law, but **by faith
> in Jesus Christ**. So we, too, have believed in Christ Jesus, that we
> may be justified by faith in Christ and not by works of the law,
> because by works of the law no one will be justified.

The simple fact that the centurion had faith in Jesus Christ, else he would not have asked Jesus to heal his servant!

Further, the fact that Jesus pronounced the centurion's faith greater than any in Israel, confirms that his faith was certainly greater than the small mustard seed (Matt 17:20) which leads to the inescapable conclusion that the centurion was a saved man.

> Acts 4:12 - Salvation exists in no one else [ie, Jesus Christ], for
> there is no other name under heaven given to men by which we must be
> saved.”

As Michael (above) has correctly pointed out about another centurion:

> Acts 10:34-36 - Then Peter began to speak: “I now truly understand
> that God does not show favoritism, but welcomes those from every
> nation who fear Him and do what is right. He has sent this message to
> the people of Israel, proclaiming the gospel of peace through Jesus
> Christ, who is Lord of all.